Why ESP32-S3-WROOM-V1 doesn't stream video on browser?
I'm trying to stream video using the IP address but what I get when I access the browser (Google Chrome) is a white screen.
I have been using the board for capturing pictures (using the same code below but different function for streaming: void startCameraServer_stream()) and it works just fine.
Arduino Setting:
USB CDC On Boot ---> Enabled
Flash Size ---> 8MB(64Mb)
Partition Scheme ---> 8M with spiffs (3MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS)
PSRAM ---> OPI PSRAM
Below the code:
    #include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
    #include <AsyncTCP.h>
    #include "esp_camera.h"
    #include "esp_system.h"
    #include <WiFi.h>
    
    const char *ssid = "*****"; //wifi name
    const char *password = "*****";//wifi password
    AsyncWebServer server(80); 
    
    #define CAMERA_MODEL_ESP32S3_EYE 
    
    #if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_ESP32S3_EYE)
    #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM  -1
    #define RESET_GPIO_NUM -1
    #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM  15
    #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM  4
    #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM  5
    #define Y2_GPIO_NUM 11
    #define Y3_GPIO_NUM 9
    #define Y4_GPIO_NUM 8
    #define Y5_GPIO_NUM 10
    #define Y6_GPIO_NUM 12
    #define Y7_GPIO_NUM 18
    #define Y8_GPIO_NUM 17
    #define Y9_GPIO_NUM 16
    #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM 6
    #define HREF_GPIO_NUM  7
    #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM  13
    
    #else
    #error "Camera model not selected"
    #endif
    
    void startCameraServer_stream(); // Video only
    void camera_settings();
    int camera_cfg();
    void wifi();
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
     
      if(camera_cfg()) { 
        wifi();
        camera_settings();
        Serial.println("Camera sensor settings applied");
        startCameraServer_stream();
      }
      else Serial.print("Fail!");
    }
    
    void loop() {
      delay(1000);
    }
    
    int camera_cfg(){
      camera_config_t config;
    
      // Camera pins configuration for ESP32-S3 
      config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
      config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
      config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_sccb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_sccb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
      config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
      config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
      config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_VGA;  
      config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG; 
      config.grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_WHEN_EMPTY; 
      config.fb_location = CAMERA_FB_IN_PSRAM;
      config.jpeg_quality = 12; 
      config.fb_count = 1; 
    
      // Initialize the camera
      esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
      if (err != ESP_OK) {
        Serial.print("Camera init failed with error 0x");
        Serial.println(err, HEX);
        return 0;
      }
      Serial.println("Camera initialized");
      return 1;
      }
    
      void camera_settings(){ 
      
      sensor_t *s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
      if (!s) {
        Serial.println("Failed to get camera sensor");
        return;
      }
    
      //Additional sensor settings for better quality
      s->set_brightness(s, 0);     // -2 to 2
      s->set_contrast(s, 0);       // -2 to 2
      s->set_saturation(s, 0);     // -2 to 2
      s->set_special_effect(s, 0); 
      s->set_whitebal(s, 1);       // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
      s->set_awb_gain(s, 1);       // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
      s->set_wb_mode(s, 0);        
      s->set_exposure_ctrl(s, 1);  // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
      s->set_aec2(s, 0);           // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
      s->set_ae_level(s, 0);       // -2 to 2
      s->set_aec_value(s, 300);    // 0 to 1200
      s->set_gain_ctrl(s, 1);      // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
      s->set_agc_gain(s, 0);       // 0 to 30
      s->set_gainceiling(s, (gainceiling_t)0);  // 0 to 6
      s->set_bpc(s, 0);            // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
      s->set_wpc(s, 1);            // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
      s->set_raw_gma(s, 1);        // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
      s->set_lenc(s, 1);           // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
      s->set_hmirror(s, 1);        // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
      s->set_vflip(s, 1);          // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
      s->set_dcw(s, 1);            // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
      s->set_colorbar(s, 0);       // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
      }
    
      void wifi(){
    
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); 
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
      delay(100);
      WiFi.setSleep(false);
    
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
            delay(1000);
            Serial.print(".");
            Serial.print("Wifi-status: ");
            Serial.println(WiFi.status()); //Check wifi status
        }
        Serial.println("Connected to Wi-Fi");
        Serial.print("IP Address: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
       }
    
       void startCameraServer_stream() { 
    
      // Set up the server to stream MJPEG video
      server.on("/stream", HTTP_GET,[] 
      (AsyncWebServerRequest*request){
        request->send_P(200, "text/html", 
          "<html><body><img src='/mjpeg_stream'></body></html>");
      });
    
      server.on("/mjpeg_stream", HTTP_GET, []
      (AsyncWebServerRequest*request) {AsyncWebServerResponse*response=
      request->beginChunkedResponse("multipart/x-mixed-replace; 
      boundary=frame", 
          [](uint8_t *buffer, size_t maxLen, size_t index) -> size_t {
            camera_fb_t *fb = esp_camera_fb_get(); 
            if (!fb) {
              Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
              return 0;
            }
    
            size_t len = fb->len;
            if (len > maxLen) {
              len = maxLen;
            }
            memcpy(buffer, fb->buf, len); // Copy frame data to buffer
            esp_camera_fb_return(fb); // Return the frame buffer
    
            return len;
          });
          
        response->addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        request->send(response);
      });
    
      server.begin();
      Serial.println("Camera server started"); 
     }

Could you help me to figure out what I'm missing?

It might help (but also maybe not) if you could format your code sensibly so that it is easy to read.

Could you be more specific? How can I format it to make it more readable?
